# Flip-up cabinet door no longer soft-closes

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I have kitchen cabinets with doors that flip open. An adjustable spring will hold them up, when opened. When you close the door, it catches the fall and the last 10cm of closing is done softly.

However, one of the cabinets has a door that violently closes because its fall is not caught, and there is no soft-close. This door used to function properly in the past.

It has two hinges like, this one on the left, one on the right.

[image]

I followed the instructions, and with a screwdriver I can move the orange part in the photo up and down. If the orange part is all the way up, the hinge is too weak to hold up the door. With the orange part all the way down it is strongest. However, this just lets me set the holding strength.

I have found no method to adjust the catching of the fall. Aren’t those soft-closes typically done w an air piston that slowly releases air? Maybe both L and R hinge are leaking?

How can I make my door soft-close again? Do I have to throw out the two hinges?

### UPDATE

I noticed that there are cylinders in there that leak oil.

I will buy new ones at Ikea. It seems that Ikea did change the spring in the last decade, so I hope the measurements are exact, and I don't have to re-drill the part at the door, and can reuse it.

Comment: Some use air pistons, some use friction to control the speed of closing.  Some also have an additional "soft close" mechanism with its own springs to pull the door firmly shut once it is almost there.  There are lots of (possibly better) versions of this hinge you might look at if you are buying new ones.  Look at woodworking hobby stores and sites.    [Here](https://www.rockler.com/shop?w=door+lift) is an example of some.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that only one hinge is failing/has failed and the other isn't strong enough on its own to soft close the door. In the top left corner of the sticker, it looks like there's some sort of "strength scale", and that these hinges are the 2nd weakest of the set they make. If they were stronger, just one might be enough to soft close the door, but the pair at a "stronger" setting might never let the door close all the way.

If the hinges *are* failing, you'll likely have to replace them. It looks like the only screws there are designed to mount it to the cabinet, not to allow it to be opened for service. I doubt there are any replaceable parts to be found inside anyway. I believe it's highly unlikely you'd be able to source quantity (2) of any of the parts in there, they're either manufactured by the hinge manufacturer or for sale at a minimum of quantity (1000).

Once you've found a replacement pair, you could tear into one to see if it's fixable - you never know what you may learn, and it won't be any more non-functional than it is now.